# Best way to initialize mongodb with eve python lib

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I'm new to python, and want to use eve as my REST API for MongoDB.
I followed the tutorials - they are pretty good and simple. But the [section](http://python-eve.org/tutorials/account_management.html) about Role-based Access Control guides on how to configure the API with role-based access but doesn't describe how to initalize the DB with data (in this example an initial superuser account).
I know I can use mongo to create the initial data manually, but I think that there is some better automated ways to do this using eve...

This question also brings out another wonderment about DB versioning - how to write upgrade code when deploying a new version of DB schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the db user needs to be already configured within mongo, or the driver (not Eve itself) won't be able to access data. User roles are Eve-specific and don't interfere with mongo users at all. Put in another way, it's an abstraction on top of the db itself.

Comment: What tools can I use to deploy mongodb with initial data and config?